# Scraping Twitter using apscheduler

Tags: python, twitter, web-scraping, web-crawler, scheduler

This is a "twitter" scraping code that extracts tweets which contain famous keywords. I would like to accumulate jobs every 12 hours.

So I wrote the code using "apscheduler".

But this is like a wrong code and I ask to ask for help.

No error message appears.

Most of the reasons that I think are wrong are that the keyword extraction is over.

However, I did not get the error phrase or the phrase that it was over,

so I think it is wrong because I do not know if it works well.

The second reason you think you're wrong is

```
sched.configure (options_from_ini_file)
```

code appears to be incorrect.

How do I solve it?
Thank you for your advice.

```
import tweepy
import time
import os
import json
import simplejson

search_term = 'x'
search_term2= 'x'
search_term3='x'
search_term4='x'
search_term5='x'

lat = "x"
lon = "x"
radius = "x"


API_key = "x"
API_secret = "x"
Access_token = "x"
Access_token_secret = "x"

location = "%s,%s,%s" % (lat, lon, radius)

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(API_key, API_secret)
auth.set_access_token(Access_token, Access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

c=tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
                q="{}+OR+{}".format(search_term, search_term2, search_term3, search_term4, search_term5),
                rpp=1000,
                geocode=location,
                include_entities=True)


data = {}
i = 1
for tweet in c.items():
    data['text'] = tweet.text
    print(i, ":", data)
    i += 1
    time.sleep(0.35)

wfile = open(os.getcwd()+"/wtt2.txt", mode='w')
data = {}
i = 0

for tweet in c.items():
    data['text'] = tweet.text
    wfile.write(data['text']+'\n')
    i += 1

wfile.close()


from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

sched = BlockingScheduler()

@sched.scheduled_job('interval', hours=12)
def timed_job():
    print('This job is run every 12 hours.')

sched.configure(options_from_ini_file)
sched.start()
```

Comment: It looks like your are running your search immediately and printing the results to the standard output. You seem to try to write results to a file, but it depends whether `c.items()` will return the same results again. Then you close the file. Then you do something with `apscheduler` which has nothing to do with `tweepy`. It looks like you should wrap your `timed_job` around the call to `tweepy`.

Comment: @quamrana Can I get advice on how to wrap time_job?